# How do I make this embedded Google Sheets chart responsive?

Tags: google-visualization

I have an embedded Google Sheets chart on my website. But, it's not responsive. How do I do it?

Here is the iframe in which the chart is embedded -

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wLbWMwwu_bXcpxm8TlkNtkR4gbeqz_o8CuRzdDQMUaM/pubchart?oid=191206948&amp;format=interactive"></iframe>
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yashghelani/o55eybur/)

Comment: Sorry. I didn't understand your question.

Comment: It cannot be changed. Google Sheets generates this url.

Comment: sorry, i didn't mean the url. let me try another way, could you elaborate on where the chart comes from? was it generated in "Google Sheets", and you want to include it on a web page? there are a couple issues here. first the chart has a hard-coded height and width. so that size will never change. unless you change the code, or what creates the code, behind the url. plus it is included in an iframe, so in your fiddle, it clips part of the chart because the iframe is not big enough to show the whole chart. so i'm not sure if you only want to fix the iframe, or make the chart itself responsive..

Comment: Yes Google Sheets generates the chart. It doesn't let you set width or height before generating the code for it I want to make the chart itself responsive.

Comment: you could try building the chart in script, similar to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38146337/5090771), but i think you would need to make the spreadsheet public...

Comment: Okay. I'll try that with the help of [this](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets)